NPM Workspace Project with Vite removing the need for the dist folder in Vite build
I have a project with a module that is using full path exports rather than index files.
The project consists of 2 NPM workspaces. The one is core the other examples.
The problem I'm trying to avoid is having an import path look like @my-project/core/dist/plugins/Input
The issue I'm facing is that I managed to have Typscript build the output such that TypeScript can compile without the need to have dist in the path, however Vite won't build as it claims it cannot find the appropriate code.
Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "@my-project/core/plugins/Input"

Typescript is just fine which was a challenge but seemed to be fixed by adding the following to my package.json
"typesVersions": {
    "*": {
      "*": [
        "./dist/*"
      ]
    }
  },

I assume this is something specific to my Vite config which looks like such:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig(() => {
  return {
    build: {
      outDir: 'build',
    },
    plugins: [
      react({
        // Use React plugin in all *.jsx and *.tsx files
        include: '**/*.{jsx,tsx}',
      }),
    ],
    server: {
      port: 3000,
      host: true,
    },
    preview: {
      port: 4000,
    },
  };
});

I have been driving myself crazy trying so many different ways to make this work and now I am halfway there by getting TypeScript to compile. I'm hoping someone out there can point out the hopefully simple mistake I'm making to have Vite work as well.

Try setting export paths in the package.json of the package you want to import. Something like this:
{
  "name": "@my-project/core",
  ...
  "exports": {
    ".": "./dist/index.js",
    "./plugins/Input": "./dist/plugins/Input",
  }
}

Then you should be able to import the subfolder as follows
import { stuff } from '@my-project/core/plugins/Input'

It's worth noting that if this package is for public consumption then you might want to add ESM and CJS export paths build both sets of outputs:
        ".": {
            "import": "./dist/index.js",
            "require": "./dist/cjs/index.cjs"
        },

Let me know how you get on!

This is exactly what I needed. I unquestioningly believed that the export would be a root and it would work from there. I didn't consider I needed each path. I really appreciate this simple solution and I learned something along the way.. Thank you!
As for the
 ".": {
            "import": "./dist/index.js",
            "require": "./dist/cjs/index.cjs"
        },

Should this be done for each of the exported paths?

No problem, please upvote as well if its correct!  Should this be done for each of the exported paths?: Yes, if you want to provide CommonJS as well as ESM in your package then you need to specify the path to each resource as CJS/ESM. If you're only providing ESM then just stick with this format ".": "./dist/index.js",
